# Set postgres db on javaproject with travis

Tags: java, postgresql, continuous-integration, travis-ci

I'm trying to put my project on travis, but i can't make a simple connection to my database. I'm using postgres.

Here is my configuration files:
Travis link: https://travis-ci.org/victorsilent/SB01/jobs/104453066

.travis.yml

```
# target programming lamguage
language: java

# JDK versios support
jdk:
  - oraclejdk7
  - oraclejdk8
addons:
  postgresql: "9.4"
sudo: required

services:
  - postgresql

# run tests, findbugs, pmd and friends using Ant, Maven or Gradle
script: ant test

before_script:
  - psql -c "create database teste2;" -U postgres
  - psql -c "create schema trabalho;" -U postgres
  - psql -c "set search_path to 'trabalho'" -U postgres
```

My test simple test

```
@Test(expected=Exception.class)
public void testeStat() throws Exception{
    try{
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver").newInstance(); 
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/teste2?currentSchema=trabalho","postgres","admin");

        Statement stmt = null;
        stmt = connection.createStatement();
        String query = "CREATE TABLE meubanco " +
            "(id INTEGER not NULL, " +
            " age INTEGER, " + 
            " PRIMARY KEY ( id ))"; 

        stmt.executeUpdate(query);
    }catch(Exception e) {
                throw new Exception(e);
    }

}
```

but my connection get rekt always!
what is wrong with these codes?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this question i change my schema to public, add

```
- pg_restore -U postgres -d bdvendas BancoVendas.backup
```

on my .travis.yml and after put my .backup database on github repository.